# Ssl error on mobile devices

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a website which is ssl installed and working properly on pc's and also on Mac.

But when I open it from mobile devices it gives an error that says server's certificate is not trusted.

You can look website at https://hepsibebek.com

What should I do to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you get your SSL certificate?  Not all certificates support mobile platforms. You can also investigate if the certificate provider provides a *certificate chain* for you to install on your site/server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You web server is not sending the intermediate certificate(s) and hence some browsers may show the warning.

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=GT65756367/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)14/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=www.hepsibebek.com
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
---
```

[image: SSL installation checker]

The steps to install and configure the intermediate certificates vary depending on the web server you are running.

You can use an SSL installation checker to validate the installation once you have made the necessary changes. for e.g. - https://ssltools.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/

Comment: very helpful. thanks. I installed the CA- G3 file at the top of my .pem file and the symantec test showed a fully trusted chain (all green). BUT the ssl labs showed weak signatures GeoTrust Global CA
SHA1: 7359755c6df9a0abc3060bce369564c8ec4542a3
RSA 2048 bits / SHA1withRSA
WEAK SIGNATURE
4  In trust store  Equifax / Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
SHA1: d23209ad23d314232174e40d7f9d62139786633a
RSA 1024 bits / SHA1withRSA
WEAK KEY IN MOZILLA'S TRUST STORE   MORE INFO »   Weak or insecure signature, but no impact on root certificates

Answer (score 1):

Your server sends only the leaf certificate, the necessary intermediate certificate is missing. Browsers might have cached this if they've seen it before with other sites, but if not they will fail to validate the certificate (or they might download the issuer certificate if this info is available inside the certificate).

See also the analysis by ssllabs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=hepsibebek.com, wich shows: "Chain issues  Incomplete".

Answer (score 1):

A certificate can contain a special *Authority Information Access* extension ([RFC-3280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280)) with URL to issuer's certificate. Most browsers can use the AIA extension to download missing intermediate certificate to complete the certificate chain. But some clients (mobile browsers, OpenSSL) don't support this extension, so they report such certificate as untrusted.

You can solve the *incomplete certificate chain* issue manually by concatenating all certificates from the certificate to the trusted root certificate (exclusive, in this order), to prevent such issues. Note, the trusted root certificate should not be there, as it is already included in the system’s root certificate store.

You should be able to fetch intermediate certificates from the issuer and concat them together by yourself. I have written a script to automate the procedure, it loops over the AIA extension to produce output of correctly chained certificates. https://github.com/zakjan/cert-chain-resolver